# Combining multiple SQL JOINs

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetValues]
@FieldName NVARCHAR(50),
@FormName NVARCHAR(50),
@PoolName NVARCHAR(50)

AS SELECT FieldValue FROM [dbo].[Values]

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Fields]
        ON [dbo].[Fields].FieldID = [dbo].[Values].FieldID

INNER JOIN [dbo].[FormFields]
        ON [dbo].[FormFields].FieldID = [dbo].[Fields].FieldID

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Forms]
        ON [dbo].[Forms].FormID = [dbo].[FormFields].FormID

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Pools]
        ON [dbo].[Pools].FormID = [dbo].[Forms].FormID

WHERE [dbo].[Fields].FieldName = @FieldName
  AND [dbo].[Forms].FormName = @FormName
  AND [dbo].[Pools].PoolName = @PoolName
```

I expected this code to filter the Values by Field, Form and Pool names. But it only filters by the Field name. What's wrong?

**Forms**

```
FormID    FormName
96        FormA
98        FormB
97        FormC
```

**Pools**

```
PoolID    FormID    PoolName
29        96        PoolA1
31        98        PoolB1
30        97        PoolC1
```

**Records**

```
RecordID    PoolID
42          29
43          29
44          29
45          31
46          31
47          31
```

**Values**

```
FieldID    RecordID    FieldValue
101        42          Yellow
101        43          Yellow
101        44          Yellow
101        45          Pink
101        46          Pink
101        47          Pink
102        42          Smith
102        43          Jones
102        44          Fletchers
103        42          Fred
103        43          Bob
103        44          Marty
```

For example, if I filter with "Favorite color" (FieldID=101), "FormA" (FormID=96) and "PoolA1" (PoolID=29), it shows "Yellow,Yellow,Yellow,Pink,Pink,Pink" whereas it should be "Yellow,Yellow,Yellow".

Comment: So no matter what you put into @FormName and @PoolName, they're ignored?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Exactly, it always seems to SELECT values from all Forms and all Pools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought, the problem was in the stored procedure itself. Everything else was fine. The JOINs were incorrectly done and that's the reason why I got erroneous results. Here's the solution:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetValues]
@FieldName NVARCHAR(50),
@FormName NVARCHAR(50),
@PoolName NVARCHAR(50)

 AS SELECT FieldValue
      FROM [dbo].[Values]

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Fields]
        ON [dbo].[Fields].FieldID = [dbo].[Values].FieldID

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Records]
        ON [dbo].[Records].RecordID = [dbo].[Values].RecordID

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Pools]
        ON [dbo].[Pools].PoolID = [dbo].[Records].PoolID

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Forms]
        ON [dbo].[Forms].FormID = [dbo].[Pools].FormID

     WHERE [dbo].[Fields].FieldName = @FieldName
       AND [dbo].[Forms].FormName = @FormName
       AND [dbo].[Pools].PoolName = @PoolName
```

Comment: I must still wait 15 hours to be allowed to accept my own answer. And BTW thanks to both you and Conrad for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest reversing the order of your WHERE statement, the query should execute faster. Run the query in SSMS with query plans turned on and you will see this clearly.

Secondly, I think it should work, have you done a SELECT * FROM with that query to make sure its not a problem of bad data.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the optimizer should take the WHERE statements into account and build the best query; the order does not matter.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152182/sql-does-the-order-of-where-conditions-matter

Comment: How SELECT * can detect a problem of bad data?

Comment: If the problem is multiple copies of the rows with bad foreign key data. Also, a SELECT *  with the same JOIN/WHERE clause might shed some light on the bad joins.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. So its got to be something else. (e.g. the TV remote is fine but the TV isn't plugged in)

1) Check that the code in the proc is really what you think it is with

```
sp_helptext 'GetValues'
```

2) Make sure that there's only one GetValues and you're not using one from a different user e.g. asmo.GetValues

```
select * from information_schema.routines where specific_name=  'GetValues'
```

3) If that fails take the SQL from inside the proc. Hardcode the parameter values and run it and see if it returns the results you think it should. If it doesn't post that sql to SO.

**EDIT** Based on your addition of the tables I tried to replicate the problem you had but the table names in the SQL and the data names aren't the same, and aren't the same in number. So I tried to synthesize the two. The following worked. I hope it helps

```
Create Database Test
GO

USE Test
GO

CREATE Table Forms
(FormID int,
FormName nvarchar(50))
GO

Create Table Pools
(PoolID int,
FormID int,
PoolName nvarchar(50))
GO

Create Table Records
(RecordID int,
PoolID int)
GO

Create Table [Values]
(FieldID int,
RecordID int,
FieldValue nvarchar(50))
GO

CREATE Table [Fields]
(
FieldID int,
FieldName nvarchar(100)
)
GO

CREATE Table [FormFields]
(
FieldID int,
FormID int
)
GO

INSERT INTO Forms (FormID, FormName) VALUES (96, 'FormA')
INSERT INTO Forms (FormID, FormName) VALUES (98, 'FormB')
INSERT INTO Forms (FormID, FormName) VALUES (97, 'FormC')
GO

INSERT INTO Pools (PoolID, FormID, PoolName) Values (29, 96, 'PoolA1')
INSERT INTO Pools (PoolID, FormID, PoolName) Values (31, 98, 'PoolB1')
INSERT INTO Pools (PoolID, FormID, PoolName) Values (30, 97, 'PoolC1')
GO

INSERT INTO Records (RecordID, PoolID) Values (42,  29)
INSERT INTO Records (RecordID, PoolID) Values (43,  29)
INSERT INTO Records (RecordID, PoolID) Values (44,  29)
INSERT INTO Records (RecordID, PoolID) Values (45,  31)
INSERT INTO Records (RecordID, PoolID) Values (46,  31)
INSERT INTO Records (RecordID, PoolID) Values (47,  31)

GO

INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (101, 42, 'Yellow')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (101, 43, 'Yellow')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (101, 44, 'Yellow')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (101, 45, 'Pink')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (101, 46, 'Pink')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (101, 47, 'Pink')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (102, 42, 'Smith')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (102, 43, 'Jones')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (102, 44, 'Fletchers')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (103, 44, 'Fred')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (103, 44, 'Bob')
INSERT INTO [Values] (FieldID, RecordID, FieldValue) Values (103, 44, 'Marty')

GO

INSERT INTO [Fields] (FieldID, FieldName) Values (101, 'Color')
INSERT INTO [Fields] (FieldID, FieldName) Values (102, 'Last Name')
INSERT INTO [Fields] (FieldID, FieldName) Values (103, 'First Name')

GO

INSERT INTO FormFields (FieldID, FormID) Values (101, 96)
INSERT INTO FormFields (FieldID, FormID) Values (102, 96)
INSERT INTO FormFields (FieldID, FormID) Values (103, 96)
INSERT INTO FormFields (FieldID, FormID) Values (101, 97)
INSERT INTO FormFields (FieldID, FormID) Values (102, 97)
INSERT INTO FormFields (FieldID, FormID) Values (103, 97)
INSERT INTO FormFields (FieldID, FormID) Values (101, 98)
INSERT INTO FormFields (FieldID, FormID) Values (102, 98)
INSERT INTO FormFields (FieldID, FormID) Values (103, 98)
GO





Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetValues]
@FieldName NVARCHAR(50),
@FormName NVARCHAR(50),
@PoolName NVARCHAR(50)

AS 

SELECT
    v.FieldValue 
FROM
    dbo.Forms f 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Pools p ON f.FormID = p.FormID
    INNER JOIN dbo.FormFields ff on f.FormID = ff.FormID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Fields fd on fd.FieldID = ff.FieldID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Records r on p.PoolID = r.PoolID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Values] v on r.RecordID  = v.RecordID 
        and ff.FieldID = v.FieldID


WHERE 
  fd.FieldName = @FieldName
  and f.FormName = @FormName
  AND p.PoolName = @PoolName
 GO



  dbo.getValues 'Color', 'FormA', 'PoolA1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I tried sp_helptext which showed me the stored procedure. The stored procedure is exactly as I posted it. Then I tried the information_schema SELECT, which returns only one version of the sproc (as expected). Finaly I executed the sproc with hardcoded parameters and I got the same results than in the GUI. So the problem must be something else...